# Добавление и обновление значений в одной функции

Tags: php, mysqli

Возможно ли добавить к существующему числу в базе данных новое число? Например, в базе данных amount = 10, надо добавить к этому числу новое значение из формы (например 15). В итоге новое значение будет 25.

Задача такая:
1. Создать форму данные которой будут добавляться в одну таблицу, назовем table_1.
2. Значение 'amount' из этой формы будет добавляться в таблицу table_1 как новая строка и в тоже время будет обновлять строку в другой таблице (table_2) прибавлением значения 'amount' к существующему числу.

То есть, если username добавил 10 amount, то в таблице table_1 добавляется новая строка. А в таблице table_2 соответствующего username будет обновляться amount с прибавлением нового значения.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table_1
                            (username, amount) 
                          VALUES    
                            ('$username','$amount')
                        ");
```

Как нужно прописать UPDATE чтобы он добавлял запись к существующему, а не обновлял старую запись на новую?

Comment: SELECT и UPDATE вам в помощь...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table_2` SET `amount` = `amount` + '$amount' where id = 101
```